# How-to: short-circuiting inverted ternary operator implemented in, e.g. C#? Does it matter?

Tags: c#, language-design, language-features

Suppose you are using the ternary operator, or the null coalescing operator, or nested if-else statements to choose assignment to an object. Now suppose that within the conditional statement, you have the evaluation of an expensive or volatile operation, requiring that you put the result into a temporary variable, capturing its state, so that it can be compared, and then potentially assigned.

How would a language, such as C#, for consideration, implement a new logic operator to handle this case? Should it? Are there existing ways to handle this case in C#? Other languages?

Some cases of reducing the verbosity of a ternary or null coalescing operator have been overcome, when we assume that we are looking for direct comparisons, for example. See [Unique ways to use the Null Coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278703/unique-ways-to-use-the-null-coalescing-operator), in particular the discussion around how one can extend the usage of the operator to support `String.IsNullOrEmpty(string)`. Note how [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is using the `PartialComparer` from [`MiscUtil`](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), to reformat `0`s to `null`s,

Why is this possibly necessary? Well, take a look at how we write a comparison method for complex objects without any shortcuts (examples from the cited discussions):

```
public static int Compare( Person p1, Person p2 )
{
    return ( (result = Compare( p1.Age, p2.Age )) != 0 ) ? result
        : ( (result = Compare( p1.Name, p2.Name )) != 0 ) ? result
        : Compare( p1.Salary, p2.Salary );
}
```

Jon Skeet writes a new comparison to fallback the equality case. This allows the expression to extend by writing a new specific method which returns null, allowing us to use the null coalescing operator:

```
return PartialComparer.Compare(p1.Age, p2.Age)
    ?? PartialComparer.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name)
    ?? PartialComparer.Compare(p1.Salary, p2.Salary)
    ?? 0;
```

The null coalescing operator is more readable because it has two sides, not three. The boolean condition clause is separated into a method, in this case returning `null` if the expression must be continued.

What would the above expression look like if we could more easily put the condition in-line? Take the expression from `PartialComparer.Compare` which returns `null`, and place it in a new ternary expression which allows us to use the evaluation of the left-side expression, with an implicit temporary variable `value`:

```
return Compare( p1.Age, p2.Age ) unless value == 0
     : Compare( p1.Name, p2.Name ) unless value == 0
     : Compare( p1.Salary, p2.Salary );
```

The basic "flow" of an expression would be:

> *expression* **A** unless *boolean* **B** in which case *expression* **C**

Rather than being an overloaded comparison operator, I suppose this is more like a short-circuiting **inverted ternary operator**.

- Would this type of logic be useful? Currently the null coalescing provides us a way to do this with the conditional expression `(value == null)`.
- What other expressions would you want to test against? We've heard of `(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))`.
- What would be the best way to express this in the language, in terms of operators, keywords?

Comment: "Not a real question", eh? I suppose "What do you use to keep notes as a developer" @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/ and "Are there any famous one-man-army programmers @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529757/ , along with others ranging from "What's your favorite programmer cartoon" to "Great programming quotes" are so much more real than discussing programming language design. I suppose I should retag one of the above tags to "subjective", but how do I do that?

Comment: Edit: Properly ended the question with a question mark.

Comment: @mpbloch : click on edit to change tags on your question. And btw, this is an interesting question, no reason to close it IMHO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

personally I'd avoid the short circuit from operators and just let the methods chain it:

```
public static int CompareChain<T>(this int previous, T a, T b)
{
    if (previous != 0)
        return previous;
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(a,b);
}
```

use like so:

```
int a = 0, b = 2;
string x = "foo", y = "bar";
return a.Compare(b).CompareChain(x,y);
```

can be inlined by the JIT so it can perform just as well as short circuiting built into the language without messing about with more complexity.

In response to your asking whether the above 'structure' can apply to more than just comparisons then yes it can, by making the choice of whether to continue or not explict and controllable by the user. This is inherently more complex but, the operation is more flexible so this is unavoidable.

```
public static T ElseIf<T>(
    this T previous, 
    Func<T,bool> isOK
    Func<T> candidate)
{
    if (previous != null && isOK(previous))
        return previous;
    return candidate();
}
```

then use like so

```
Connection bestConnection = server1.GetConnection()
    .ElseIf(IsOk, server2.GetConnection)
    .ElseIf(IsOk, server3.GetConnection)
    .ElseIf(IsOk, () => null);
```

This is maximum flexibility in that you can alter the *IsOk* check at any stage and are entirely lazy. For situations where the is OK check is the same in every case you can simplify like so and entirely avoid extensions methods.

```
public static T ElseIf<T>(        
    Func<T,bool> isOK
    IEnumerable<Func<T>[] candidates)
{
   foreach (var candidate in candidates)
   { 
        var t = candidate();
        if (isOK(t))
            return t;
   }
   throw new ArgumentException("none were acceptable");
}
```

You could do this with linq but this way gives a nice error message and allows this

```
public static T ElseIf<T>(        
    Func<T,bool> isOK
    params Func<T>[] candidates)
{
    return ElseIf<T>(isOK, (IEnumerable<Func<T>>)candidates);
}
```

style which leads to nice readable code like so:

```
var bestConnection = ElseIf(IsOk,
    server1.GetConnection,
    server2.GetConnection,
    server3.GetConnection);
```

If you want to allow a default value then:

```
public static T ElseIfOrDefault<T>(        
    Func<T,bool> isOK
    IEnumerable<Func<T>>[] candidates)
{
   foreach (var candidate in candidates)
   { 
        var t = candidate();
        if (isOK(t))
            return t;
   }
   return default(T);
}
```

Obviously all the above can very easily be written using lambdas so your specific example would be:

```
var bestConnection = ElseIfOrDefault(
    c => c != null && !(c.IsBusy || c.IsFull),
    server1.GetConnection,
    server2.GetConnection,
    server3.GetConnection);
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you helped me check my use of C# 3 above. I like where you were taking this, but wanted to cover more cases than "Comparison".

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I knew that C# was a pretty expressive language, and that there were certainly ways to do this with a handful of methods, and so posed the original question to see if it would add anything by expressing this logic with such an operator. But, you have certainly demonstrated the expressiveness offered by the existing language very completely. The example you provided seems complete and to address any case in which the "logic operation" proposed would apply. The ElseIf generic method, and the ElseIfOrDefault methods you provide seem extremely flexible.

Comment: If you enjoy this then I suggest taking a look at functional languages in general (f# being a pleasant way to do this if you are used to .Net)

Answer (score 2):

You've got lots of good answers to this question already, and I am late to this particular party. However I think it is worthwhile to note that your proposal is a special case of a more generally useful operation which I dearly wish C# had, namely, the ability to in an expression context, give a name to a temporary computation.

In fact C# has this operator but *only in query comprehensions*. I wish we had been able to add this as an operator in C# 3:

```
public static int Compare(Person p1, Person p2) =>
  let ages = Compare(p1.Age, p2.Age) in
    ages != 0 ? 
      ages : 
      let names = Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name) in
      names != 0 ? 
        names : 
        Compare(p1.Salary, p2.Salary);
```

"Let expressions" are one of those expressions that are *so useful*, and found in *so few languages*, and I genuinely do not understand why language designers do not add it immediately in version one.

If C# had this feature then your proposed:

```
A() unless B() : C()
```

is simply

```
let a = A() in B() ? C() : a
```

which is hardly more difficult to understand, and bonus, you get to use `a` in expressions `B()` and `C()` if you like.

Let expressions can be emulated in any language that has lambdas; of course `let x = y in z` is simply `(x=>z)(y)`, but there is no concise way to write that in C# either because C# requires a conversion to a delegate type on every lambda.

Incidentally, in Roslyn we do not represent temporaries as let-expressions, though we could. Rather, we go even one level below that and have a representation for "sequence of operations that might produce values, one of which will become the value of this expression".  "let x = y in z" is simply the sequence "allocate x, x = y, z, deallocate x" where the third element is the value.  And in the original pre-roslyn C# compiler we had internal operators "left" and "right", which were binary operators that took two expressions and produced either the left or right side, so we could generate `((allocate x) right ((x = y) right z)) left (deallocate x)`.

My point here is: we often get requests for bespoke language features with unusual punctuation, but it would in general have been better to implement the *basic building blocks* that you could build these operators out of in a natural way.

Answer (score 0):

To place one proposed implementation away from a very verbose question, let's run with the `unless` keyword.

(expression **A**) `unless` (boolean **B**) <magical "in which case" operator> (expression **C**)

... would be all there is to it.

Boolean expression **B** would have access to the evaluation of expression **A** through the keyword `value`. Expression **C** could have the `unless` keyword in its expression, allowing for simple, linear chaining.

Candidates for the <magical "in which case" operator>:

- `:`
- `|`
- `?:`
- `otherwise` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Usage of any symbols tend to diminish readability for the average developer. Even the `??` operator is not used widely. I, myself, do prefer to develop verbose code, but that I can easily read one year from now.

So a candidate for your :

> *expression* A unless *boolean* B in which case *expression* C.

would be

*expression* A unless *boolean* B sothen *expression* C.

Although many people like me would still use:

```
if (B) {expression C;}
else {expression A;}
```

This comes in when you are developing a software with a big team, with different backgrounds, each one on the team master of one language, and just user of others.

Comment: However, the use case represented here does not allow one to easily use `if (B) C else A`, because B depends on the evaluation of C or A.

Answer (score 0):

More @[ShuggyCoUk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12748/shuggycouk): Ah, I see that this might work for more than just comparisons? I haven't used C# 3 and extension methods, but I suppose you can declare, for my previous example, below, a

```
public delegate bool Validation<T>( T toTest );
public static T Validate<T>( this T leftside, Validation<T> validator )
{
    return validator(leftside) ? leftside : null;
}
```

Followed by, per Skeet:

```
Validation<Connection> v = ( Connection c ) => ( c != null && !( c.IsBusy || c. IsFull ) );
Connection bestConnection =
    server1.GetConnection().Validate( v ) ??
    server2.GetConnection().Validate( v ) ??
    server3.GetConnection().Validate( v ) ?? null;
```

Is this how that would work in C#? Comments appreciated. Thank you.

---

In response to [ShuggyCoUk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12748/shuggycouk):

So this is an extension method in C# 3, then? Also, the result here is an int, not an arbitrary expression. Useful for overloading yet another comparison method. Suppose I wanted an expression for choosing the best connection. Ideally, I want something to simplify the following:

```
Connection temp;
Connection bestConnection =
    ( temp = server1.GetConnection() ) != null && !(temp.IsBusy || temp.IsFull) ? temp
    :   ( temp = server2.GetConnection() ) != null && !(temp.IsBusy || temp.IsFull ) ? temp
        :   ( temp = server3.GetConnection() ) != null && !(temp.IsBusy || temp.IsFull ) ? temp
            : null;
```

Ok, so one could have a method

```
bool IsOk( Connection c )
{
    return ( c != null && !(c.IsBusy || c.IsFull) );
}
```

Which would produce:

```
Connection temp;
Connection bestConnection =
    ( temp = server1.GetConnection() ) && IsOk( temp ) ? temp
    :   ( temp = server2.GetConnection() ) && IsOk( temp ) ? temp
        :   ( temp = server3.GetConnection() ) && IsOk( temp ) ? temp
            : null;
```

But how would method chaining for comparisons work, here? I am pondering something which looks like:

```
Connection bestConnection =
    server1.GetConnection() unless !IsOk(value) otherwise
    server2.GetConnection() unless !IsOk(value) otherwise
    server3.GetConnection() unless !IsOk(value) otherwise null;
```

I think that there are so far, hoops to jump through, if I want the result of a conditional to be an expression or result of a method which was in the original conditional.

I assume that the object returned by such methods will be expensive to produce, or will change the next time the method is called.

Comment: outlined how to use my functional approach with the revised example in edit to my original answer