# C# StringComparer: Optional Argument Default

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, default-value

I'm attempting to create a method which checks whether a `String` contains any `Strings` contained within an `IEnumerable<String>`.My method so far is this:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAny(this String Self, IEnumerable<String> Fragments, StringComparer CompareType = StringComparer.CurrentCulture)
{
    foreach (var fragment in Fragments)
    {
        if (Self.Contains(fragment,CompareType))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, this won't compile because `StringComparer.CurrentCulture` ins't a compile time constant as shown by this error:

```
> Error 1   Default parameter value for 'CompareType' must be a
> compile-time constant
```

My question is, what is an acceptable default value which I can use for `CompareType` which will result in the same behavior as if it were possible to have it default to `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, cleanest, and consistent (with framework) is to have overloads:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAny(this String Self, IEnumerable<String> Fragments)
{
    returns ContainsAny(Self, Fragments, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
}

public static Boolean ContainsAny(this String Self, IEnumerable<String> Fragments, StringComparer CompareType)
{
    foreach (var fragment in Fragments)
    {
        if (Self.Contains(fragment,CompareType))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you do want only one overload, then may be:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAny(this String Self, IEnumerable<String> Fragments, StringComparer CompareType = null)
{
    if (CompareType == null)
        ComapreType = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;

    foreach (var fragment in Fragments)
    {
        if (Self.Contains(fragment,CompareType))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Suggestions:

1. Use language aliases like `bool` instead of `Boolean`. Its recommended and makes code short.
2. In C# parameter names starts with lower case (camelCase)
3. If you have `Linq`, the code is as sweet as:

   ```
   return Fragments.Any(x => self.Contains(x, compareType));
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I like the first approach's method of dealing with the problem, especially as I don't need to implement it with only one method.

Comment: Part of the reason why overloads are "consistent with frameworks" is that default arguments are relatively new to the C# language. Prior to them, all frameworks used overloads, so they kept them after the introduction of default parameters for backward compatibility.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I agree, so plus 1 to you.. :) Personally I like and use optional parameters! The only thing I hate about it is to see `[....]` brackets in intellisense! :)

Answer (score 3):

A common trick to deal with non-compile-time constants is moving the check to runtime, like this:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAny(
    this String self
,   IEnumerable<String> fragments
,   StringComparer comparerArg = null)
{
    var comparer = comparerArg ?? StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
    ...
}
```

You make `null` the default in the method signature, and then the first thing you check is if the value passed is `null`, in which case you substitute it with `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`. Note that in order for this trick to work, `null` must not be a valid parameter that one would reasonably want to pass to your method, and your documentation should say that passing `null` is equivalent to passing `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: I learnt something new from your answer -- the `??` operator, I would have normally used a ` _ ? X : Y`, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @HennyH they are called [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator. Pretty much a standard thing across languages. They return the second argument if first is null, otherwise the first. See this question for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278703/unique-ways-to-use-the-null-coalescing-operator