# Optional Chaining or ternary expression in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicolor, optional-variables

Is there a more efficient, readable or more modern way of writing the following?

```
let currentColor:UIColor = view.backgroundColor != nil 
  ? view.backgroundColor! // forced unwrapping
  : UIColor.whiteColor() // fallback value
```

I don't mind using a ternary operator here, but it feels like I should be using the Swift `if let currentColor = view.backgroundColor` syntax. I'm just not sure how that would look to specify a default value.

Comment: Is it pure coincidence that the questions are so similar? An almost identical question has been asked (and answered) two hours ago.

Comment: @MartinR Hilarious... I searched but didn't find a quick answer. Fascinating. I wonder if it has to do with the TeamTreehouse course that has a random number generator lesson in it applying to color.

Comment: Reading that Q/A now... yeah pretty much the same. If you searched using google, maybe it was not indexed yet :)

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, I was surprised to realize it was a different person.

Comment: What's even funnier is that one my top voted question is on using the Null coalescing operator `??` in C# several years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278703/unique-ways-to-use-the-null-coalescing-operator Glad to see this in Swift.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124):

```
let currentColor: UIColor = view.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.whiteColor()
```

If `view.backgroundColor` is not nil, it is used for the assignment, otherwise what comes to the right of `??`

Comment: Woo hoo! just like `C#` and it's null coalescing operator! Thanks!