# Can I echo multiple html tags containing php variables with a single echo?

Tags: php, syntax, refactoring

Do I really need this many echo's or can I make it shorter?

```
<?php
if (!empty($url))
{
    echo '<p>Job: <span>' . $job .'</span></p>';
    echo '<p>Skills: <span class="caps">' . $skills . '</span></p>';
    echo '<p>Website: <a href="http://' . $url . '" title="' . $url . '">http://' . $url . '</a></p>';
    echo '<p>Pay:' . $pay. '</p>';
} else { 
    echo'';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Why not revert it?

```
<?php if(!empty($url)) { ?>
 <p>Job: <span><?=$job?></span></p>
 <p>Skills: <span class="caps"><?=$skills?></span></p>
 <p>Website: <a href="http://<?=$url?>/" title="<?=$url?>">http://<?=$url?></a></p>
 <p>Pay: <?=$pay?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Note that short tags like `<?` instead of `<?php` may be turned off on some PHP installations.

Comment: True. The thing to watch out for.

Comment: that be a nice way to do it there, arrrr.  also look into if: endif: syntax.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/php-difference-between-if-and-if-endif

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but I really don't like this verbose syntax.

Comment: I don't really understand the appeal of if:endif. If your code is properly indented, there should never be any ambiguity that would require endif.

Comment: eyelidlessness, moreover, if you have nested `if`s, `endif` is still ambigous ;-)

Comment: Good solution for this specific case, but it doesn't actually answer the question as it does not actually use echo.

Comment: Citizen, there's no `echo` requirement. The question is whether one needs *this many echos* or one *can make it shorter* ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Sure, and there's no need for an `else` that does nothing:

```
<?php

if(!empty($url)) {
  echo "<p>Job: <span>{$job}</span></p>";
  echo "<p>Skills: <span class=\"caps\">{$skills}</span></p>";
  echo "<p>Website: <a href=\"http://{$url}\" title=\"{$url}\">http://{$url}</a></p>";
  echo "<p>Pay: {$pay}</p>";
}

?>
```

... or even:

```
<?php

if(!empty($url)) {
  echo "<p>Job: <span>{$job}</span></p>
        <p>Skills: <span class=\"caps\">{$skills}</span></p>
        <p>Website: <a href=\"http://{$url}\" title=\"{$url}\">http://{$url}</a></p>
        <p>Pay: {$pay}</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to concatenate multiple lines or revert if you want to use echo. The actual answer to your question is this (because it still uses echo):

```
  <?php
        if (!empty($url))
        {
        echo '<p>Job: <span>' . $job .'</span></p>
    <p>Skills: <span class="caps">' . $skills . '</span></p>
        <p>Website: <a href="http://' . $url . '" title="' . $url . '">http://' . $url . '</a></p>
        <p>Pay:' . $pay. '</p>';
        }
        ?>
```

Php doesnt care how many lines you use.

Comment: It does. It won't be the same output, it will be infested with whitespace.

Comment: Infested? This method will have the appropriate html formatting. p tags are supposed to be done on new lines in most code conventions.

Comment: "appropriate" for what? Often the most appropriate html formatting is the one that takes less bytes. And, assuming, `p` is not a top-level element it's going to be broken, anyway.

Comment: The use is choosing to go multiline for the html for the same reason... html should be easy to maintain and read as well. Unless a few bytes are an issue, returns are not all bad.

Comment: "easy to maintain"? Easy to maintain automatically generated html? What are you talking about? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could either :

- use the dot (`.`) for strings concatenation, and use a single `echo`
- or use several strings in a single `echo`, separated by commas '`,`'

See the [`echo` manual page](http://php.net/echo), for examples.

For the first solution :

```
echo 'a' . 'b' . 'c';
```

And, for the second :

```
echo 'd', 'e', 'f';
```

And the output will be :

```
abcdef
```

Another solution would be to use variable interpolation in [double-quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) :

```
$my_var = "test";
echo "this is a $my_var";
```

Which will get you :

```
this is a test
```

For instance, using a bit of both :

```
$job = 'my job';
$skills = 'my skills';
$url = 'google.com';
$pay = 3.14;

echo "<p>Job: <span>$job</span></p>"
    . "<p>Skills: <span class=\"caps\">$skills</span></p>"
    . "<p>Website: <a href=\"http://$url\" title=\"$url\">http://$url</a></p>"
    . "<p>Pay:$pay</p>";
```

You'll get :

```
Job: my job
Skills: my skills
Website: http://google.com
Pay:3.14
```

But note that you'll have to escape the `"`, which is not easy to do :-(

So, yet another solution, based on [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

```
echo <<<STR
<p>Job: <span>$job</span></p>
<p>Skills: <span class="caps">$skills</span></p>
<p>Website: <a href="http://$url" title="$url">http://$url</a></p>
<p>Pay:$pay</p>
STR;
```

Only one `echo`, no string concatenation, no escaping -- what else could one ask for ?

;-)

Comment: You don't have to escape the ", you can use single quotes in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this would do the job too:

```
echo '<p>Job: <span>' . $job .'</span></p><p>Skills: <span class="caps"></span></p><p>Website: <a href="http://' . $url . '" title="' . $url . '">http://' . $url . '</a></p><p>Pay:' . $pay. '</p>';
```

You may add `\n`s for more readable HTML.

Or you may use this one which is more readable on the PHP side:

```
echo "<p>Job: <span>{$job}</span></p><p>Skills: <span class=\"caps\"></span></p><p>Website: <a href=\"http://{$url}\" title=\"{$url}\">http://{$url}</a></p><p>Pay:{$pay}</p>";
```

Or you could use the heredoc syntax which is even more readable:

```
echo <<<HTML
    <p>Job: <span>$job</span></p>
    <p>Skills: <span class="caps"></span></p>
    <p>Website: <a href="http://$url" title="$url">http://$url</a></p>
    <p>Pay:$pay</p>
HTML;
```

At last you can cut the else branch if you really want to `echo` - well - nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that with single echo and concatenation, which is just "." , and yes you ll need one more echo for the else stmt.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try [sprintf](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). 
You can do something like:

```
<?php echo sprintf('<p>Job: <span>%s</span></p>', $job); ?>
```

Comment: you just made it worse!  now instead of a ton of echo's, he's got a ton of sprintf's as well.  hacker's answer works well.

Comment: echo "<p>{$job</p>";

or

echo '<p>'.$job.'</p>';

Are both more efficient.

Comment: I didn't mean replace the echos with a ton of sprintfs, I meant replace all of them with one sprintf - I was hoping he would extrapolate that without me going to the effort of typing out his entire string.

Comment: That's true, Citizen, I wanted to write a comment like that too, but then I thought - why would one want to use php if performance is *that* much of a concern ;-)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is a really weird replacement for `printf`, btw ;-)

Comment: I agree with Michael.  `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern".  There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would start using templates if i were you. there are a multitude of templating engines out there.. I highly recommend Smarty. http://www.smarty.net/

This will allow you to separate your code from your display logic. This means that you can choose a different template, or give your template to a designer, who does not need to know anything about php. It will also allow you to go over your code at a later date and easily debug/change it. Nothing worse than trying to read code that has html and php intermingled throughout.

code:

```
//this part will instigate a copy of smarty
require_once('/location_of_smarty_lib/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$blah = new Smarty();
$blah ->template_dir = '/location_of_smarty_lib/smarty/templates';
$blah ->compile_dir  = '/location_of_smarty_lib/smarty/templates_c';
$blah ->cache_dir    = '/location_of_smarty_lib/smarty/cache';
$blah ->config_dir   = '/location_of_smarty_lib/smarty/configs';

//this part assigns variables to tags
$blah->assign('t_url',$url);
$blah->assign('t_job',$job);
$blah->assign('t_skills',$skills);
$blah->assign('t_pay',$pay);
//this will display the out put using the given template
$blah->display('yargh.tpl');
```

template (called yargh.tpl):

```
{if $t_url}
 <p>Job: <span>{$t_job}</span></p>
 <p>Skills: <span class="caps">{$t_skills}</span></p>
 <p>Website: <a href="http://{$t_url}/" title="{$t_url}">http://{$t_url}</a></p>
 <p>Pay: {$t_pay}</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Are you using a pirate theme in that template example?

Comment: php is a template engine that happens to be used for other things as well. it was designed to integrate easily with markup languages. why complicate it with things like smarty?

Comment: that is true.. but have you tried editing someones code who has mixed their display logic with their php code... It gets nighmare like, both in the short term and the long term.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good opportunity to use `printf()` so that you don't need to bounce in and out of `<?php`/`?>` tags.

Create a clean template string with placeholders with HEREDOC syntax so that you don't need to worry about juggling and escaping quotation marks.

Because you are using the `$url` variable more than once, use numbered placeholders so make your code more D.R.Y.

```
$template = <<<HTML
    <p>Job: <span>%1$s</span></p>
    <p>Skills: <span class="caps">%2$s</span></p>
    <p>Website: <a href="http://%3$s" title="%3$s">http://%3$s</a></p>
    <p>Pay: %4$s</p>
HTML;
if (!empty($url)) {
    printf($template, $job, $skills, $url, $pay);
}
```

Using placeholders like this makes your code very easy to maintain.  Removing the noise of variables and concatenation may help you to identify typos/mistakes -- such as a missing space after `Pay:`.

Answer (score -1):

You can, but would it be best to keep it as is for readability purposes?  I don't think it will hurt the performance of your script having multiple echos.

Comment: I find that sort of concatenation less readable than some alternatives, though.

Comment: If there's no need for mulitples, you shouldn't have them.

Comment: @Citizen Not necessarily. Sometimes, a few extra echo statements drastically improves readability with essentially zero performance loss.