# Convert and array into an ordered list of input fields

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array of sites like so...

```
$data = array(
'http://site1.net/',
'http://site2.net/',
'http://site3.org/'
);
```

And I'd like to create a script that iterates over the array and creates a list of input text fields containing each array element...

```
Example:
 1. [] http://site1.net/
 2. [] http://site2.net/
 3. [] http://site2.net/
```

Where [] represents the checkbox element and the URL is inside an input text field.

```
<ol>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><input type="text" id="text1" value="http://site1.net/" /></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><input type="text" id="text2" value="http://site2.net/" /></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><input type="text" id="text3" value="http://site3.net/" /></li>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $site)
{
    printf('<li><input type="checkbox" id="check%d" /><input type="text" id="text%d" value="%s" /></li>', $key, $key, $site);
}
```

Comment: Actually, that will give you "check0", etc. If you want to start at 1, just use $key + 1.

Comment: echo sprintf() is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write echo sprintf() in any code for any reason -- it should be printf() every time.

Comment: Updated per comment above.

Comment: Ha.  Nope. Cut that `echo` out of there! :)  And please include an educational explanation while editing.  Because you are using `$key` twice, you should use numbered placeholders and only offer `$key` as a parameter of `printf()` once.  Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71794752/2943403

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $data as $item ) {

echo "<input type='checkbox' ... "

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = array(
'http://site1.net/',
'http://site2.net/',
'http://site3.org/'
);

function getCechkbox($array)
{
foreach( $array as $key=>$item ) 
  echo "$item :<input type='checkbox'>";
}

<form action="select.htm">
  <p>
  <?php getCechkbox($data); ?>
  </p>
</form>
```