# Using if() {} vs if(): endif;

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between if () { } and if () : endif;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif)

Simple question,

When I started programming PHP I was shown my if statements like this:

```
If(1 == 1):
Echo 'hello world';
Endif;
```

Where as most people prefer

```
If(1== 1) {
Echo 'hello world';
}
```

Is there any difference? Does is improve the speed of the script or is it Better than the way I do it?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif

Comment: Is the samething. PHP will run with the same speed, no difference. The same for `<?` vs `<?php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement are equals though for a better legibility in a Model View Controller project is better to use

```
if(1== 1) {
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

in model/controller part and the other one in the View part.

```
<? if(1 == 1): ?>
   <div>..</div>
<? endif;?>
```

so a web designer/ graphic can better handle html code.

Comment: Saying that the different syntax is something aimed at MVC is a little misguided.

Comment: @jprofitt: maybe my english did not help. I just wanted to say that the different syntax make sense in a MVC and I explained why.

Answer (score 1):

No. However, you should not think about micro optimization (it's the root of all evil), especially since you name yourself a beginner.

The second one is more common, the first one is often more readable when mixing php and html.

Comment: +1 - Premature optimisation is never a good idea either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no speed difference between them. This is an alternate syntax of `if`.

Some people prefer `if() {` or some prefer `if ():`

I personally use if (): when there is a bunch of HTML need to output.

```
<?php if (condition) : ?>
//some html tags html
<?php endif; ?>
```

and I use `if(condition) {` when some php processing to be done.

```
<?php
if (condition)
{
   //other PHP stuff
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use alternative syntax when I mix PHP with HTML (its much cleaner this way for me):

```
    <p>
        <label>Customer:</label>
        <?php echo Form::input('customer', Arr::get($post, 'customer'), array('maxlength' => 80)) ?>
        <?php if (isset($errors['customer'])): ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $errors['customer'] ?></span>
        <?php endif ?>
    </p>
```

Other then that there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference? Does is improve the speed of the script or is it Better than the way I do it?

No.
That's just two different ways to do the same thing.

For the second one almost every good code editor/IDE will highlight the matching brace.
Such a reason, along with the fact that curly braces are compatible with many other languages, makes them used more often.