# if {} in if: endif

Tags: php

Why it won't work? Appears Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' ... on line 7

```
$a = 0; $b = 1; $c = 3; $d = 4;
if ($a == $b):
   if ($b == $c) {
       // something
   }
else:
   $c = $a;
endif;
```

But if i change it to (just added else statement):

```
$a = 0; $b = 1; $c = 3; $d = 4;
if ($a == $b):
   if ($b == $c) {
       // something
   } else {
       // something
   }
else:
   $c = $a;
endif;
```

It works fine.

Why is that? isn't it a PHP bug? Or there is a rule about if...else i should know?

Anyway, i'm using PHP 5.3.3 version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif

Comment: Interesting - and a good illustration of why you probably shouldn't mix the templating style flow control statements with the regular braced ones. (or use the templating style _at all_ unless you're coding an HTML view... but that's opinion)

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Looks like the alternative else is being connected to the inner if. I wonder if you could wrap the inner if in parenthesis or something.

Comment: @NullUserException Dangling else doesnt seem to be the case here. Even though the op mixed the syntax, each of the if else are grouped correctly, it will never be the case [if (if else else)] or [(if if else) else], it has to be [if (if else) else]

Comment: @itachi the issue might not have been voluntary, though, you should not be so eager to criticize...

Comment: @Churk As I understand it, In the first example, the `else:` is being attached to the inner `if` and throwing an error because it uses the alternative syntax instead of the expected `{`

Comment: @MikeB I miss read the question, I though the top works while the bottom one does not. So Dangling else is the issue.

Comment: @damien: i am not criticising. Its just a matter of opinion. Some people find it interesting, i feel it knit picking issues, like, solving a problem which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure if I would call this is a bug, but I believe you're having this issue because of a [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), in conjunction with your mixed if-else syntax:

```
if ($a == $b):            // 1
    if ($b == $c) {       // 2 
        // something      // 3
    }                     // 4
else:                     // 5 - this else
    $c = $a;              // 6
endif;                    // 7
```

Note how the `else` on line 5 is ambiguous: it could "belong" either to the first or second `if` statements.

You can easily remove that ambiguity and fix your syntax error by adding a semicolon after your nested `if`:

```
if ($a == $b):            // 1
    if ($b == $c) {       // 2 
        // something      // 3
    };                    // 4 - here
else:                     // 5 
    $c = $a;              // 6
endif;                    // 7
```

On another note, please don't use this syntax unless you want your fellow programmers to bludgeon you to death in your sleep.

Comment: About what I was going to write. Only better. :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I won't mix syntax. it just a little wonder that turns into question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments on the [PHP manual's control structure page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) the parser appears to not always assume that an `if` from one style should not be matched with an `else` using the other.

Answer (score 0):

The colon form of the if/else can be ambiguous when dealing with nested ifs.  In your example the else is being attached the the second if (as it should.)  In order to avoid this you must explicitly let the interpreter know that that else is paired with the first if, either by adding an else to the second if (as you show in your second code block), or using {} to explicitly define the control flow.

In other words, you can use multiple forms of if statements. For example:

```
if (foo):
  //statements
else {
  //statements
}
```

Is perfectly valid.  Although I would advise against mixing forms since it takes away from the readability.

Answer (score 0):

By PSD standards, always use brackets.

```
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;
if ($a == $b) {
    if ($b == $c) {
        // something
    } else {
        $c = $a;
    }
}
```

Its more readable, safer and clear.

Comment: You appear to be making dozens of edits to question after running their codeblocks through an automated formatting tool. Please stop doing this, there is no objectively "right" way to format PHP, and people are free to post using whatever format they like.