# Why does Magento not use curly brackets to surround code blocks?

Tags: php, magento, conditional-statements, brackets

As I check through Magento, they tend not to use starting and ending curly brackets (braces) in the code. For example generally we use **{** and **}** brackets in the code but in Magento, they are using **:** or **endif**.

Can you please let me know why they don't use curly brackets and what is the use of **:** and **endif** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a coding standard followed in magento for the phtml files.

Comment: Check Zend framework coding standard.

Comment: Hello Muk, Is there any strong reason for using **endif;** condition ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this:

[Difference between if () { } and if () : endif;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif)

Is part of the coding standard but there isn't really a very clear advantage to it.

Comment: Hello claudiu.brand, Is there any strong reason for using **endif;** in place of **brackets** in the condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in Magento, `if()` statements (et.al.) will use curly brackets to surround code blocks in module code programming and libraries (files ending in `.php`) and will use the alternate syntax `<?php if(): >` `<?php endif; >` in `.phtml` files where you find PHP code interspersed with html code.

It's mostly a coding decision to separate html and php code for readability when you are writing templates.