# How Can I Fix the Following For-loop and If statement combination in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

Edit:  Solved!  Thank you all for pointing out the missing concatenation operator and missing punctuation.

I've just been introduced to PHP and am trying to work on a basic exercise where I use a for-loop in combination with several if/elseif statements.

My variables A and B are related mathematically, and I need the output to state the value of B along with a simple word ('Good', 'bad', 'okay'- depending on the resultant value of B).  I'd also like each result of the loop to be printed on a new line.

My attempt can be seen below:

```
<?php

for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++){
$B = (2/3) * ($A - 25); 

if ($B < 0 {
echo $B ", Bad <br>";}

elseif ($B > 45 {
echo $B ", Good <br>";}

else {
echo $B ", Okay <br>";}
}

endfor;
?>
```

This is only my second day of working with PHP (and the first time I've written a loop statement of any kind in about seven years) so I apologize if my errors are glaring.

Do I need to move my definition of $B?  Do I need to split this statement up somehow?  Is it my echo statements that are the issue?  Any hints or explanations are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is some syntax error in your code use `.` for concatenation in **PHP**

and there is two types syntax for control structures [detail link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) , either use `if( some condition ){ your code }` or `if(some condition): "your code" endif;` .
here is the [Difference between if () { } and if () : endif;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif)

```
<?php

for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++):
$B = (2/3) * ($A - 25); 

    if($B < 0 ){
        echo $B .", Bad <br>";
    }else if ($B > 45) {
        echo $B .", Good <br>";
    }else{
        echo $B .", Okay <br>";
    }

endfor;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some Syntax errors in your code. You have missed `)` as well as concatenation operator i.e. `.`

```
if ($B < 0 {    //  if ($B < 0)  .... ")" is missing
    echo $B ", Bad <br>";}    //  echo $B .", Bad <br>";}  .... "." is missing
```

here is corrected code :

```
for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++){
    $B = (2/3) * ($A - 25); 

    if ($B < 0) {
        echo $B . " Bad <br>";
    }

elseif ($B > 45) {
echo "Good <br>";}

else {
echo "Okay <br>";}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++){
$B = (2/3) * ($A - 25); 

if ($B < 0) {
echo $B .", Bad <br>";
}

elseif ($B > 45) {
echo $B ."Good <br>";
}

   else {
   echo $B ."Okay <br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++) {
    $B = (2 / 3) * ($A - 25);
    if ($B < 0) {
        echo $B . " Bad <br>";
    } else if ($B > 45) {
        echo "Good <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Okay <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had missed the closing paranthesis `)` for the `if` and `elseif` block and the concatenation operator `.` in the first echo statement. `echo` accepts and outputs one string and so you need to combine several strings to make it one and ask `echo` to output it. `endfor;` is also not required.

```
<?php

for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++)
{ 
$B = (2/3) * ($A - 25);
if ($B < 0) 
{ 
echo $B.", Bad <br>";
}
elseif ($B > 45 )
{
 echo "Good <br>";
}
else 
{ 
echo "Okay <br>";
} 
}
?>
```

Using `endfor;`

```
for ($A = 0; $A <= 100; $A++):
$B = (2/3) * ($A - 25);
if ($B < 0) 
{ 
echo $B.", Bad <br>";
}
elseif ($B > 45 )
{
 echo "Good <br>";
}
else 
{ 
echo "Okay <br>";
} 
endfor;
```

I have replaced the opening `{` of the for loop with `:` and the closing brace with `endfor;`

This is how it works.

Comment: echo $B ", Bad <br>";   // Error