# Date selector with 30 min increments

Tags: php

I need to write a selector of time in 30 min increments, like this:

```
<option value="10:00">10:00 am</option>
<option value="10:30">10:30 am</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00 am</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30 am</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00 pm</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30 pm</option>
<option value="13:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="13:30">1:30 pm</option>
...
<option value="23:00">11:00 pm</option>
<option value="23:30">11:30 pm</option>
```

One way to do it is to put this all in an array and loop through using key=>value pairs. However, I'd rather have it as a php loop.

So I found the following interesting function:

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
        echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                       .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
```

It gets me close. To modify it to suit my needs I reshuffled a few things like this:

```
echo '<select>';
    for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'

        $thrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $tmin = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $tstr = $thrs.':'.$tmin;

        echo '
        <option value="'.$tstr.'">
              '.$tstr.' '.($thrs > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am').'
        </option>';

echo '</select>';
```

However, something breaks and I get a single value: 23:60 pm

What am I  missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your loops in brackets.

```
echo '<select>';
for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++) { // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) { // the interval for mins is '30'

        $thrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $tmin = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $hrs = $thrs;
        if ($thrs > 12) $hrs = $thrs - 12;
        $tstr = $hrs.':'.$tmin;

        echo '
        <option value="'.$tstr.'">
              '.$tstr.' '.($thrs > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am').'
        </option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

The original code you did was equivalent to this:

```
echo '<select>';
for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++) { // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) { // the interval for mins is '30'

        $thrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    }
}
$tmin = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$tstr = $thrs.':'.$tmin;

echo '
        <option value="'.$tstr.'">
              '.$tstr.' '.($thrs > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am').'
        </option>';

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Uh, oops. It works now but the value is printing 15:30 pm instead of 3:30 pm... I guess I wasn't as close as I thought.

Comment: Adjusted to not use military time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use do it on client side using javascript? Beside that, your PHP code lacks of code block for the for loops

```
echo '<select>';
    for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
{  //<====
        $thrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        $tmin = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $tstr = $thrs.':'.$tmin;

        echo '
        <option value="'.$tstr.'">
              '.$tstr.' '.($thrs > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am').'
        </option>';
}  //<====
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly you forgot curly brackets `{}` in for loop. Because you iterate nested `for` loop so it is mandatory to set `{}` brackets.

**Solution 1 (With curly brackets):**

```
for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++){ // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30){ // the interval for mins is '30'
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 (Alternate [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif)):**

```
for($hours=3; $hours<24; $hours++): // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30): // the interval for mins is '30'
        // Do stuff.
    endfor;
endfor;
```