# Beautify C++ code to add brackets to conditional statements

Tags: c++

How can I beautify C++ code to add brackets to conditional statements? What I need to do is change:

```
if ( myCondition )
    setDateTime( date, time );
```

to

```
if ( myCondition )
{
    setDateTime( date, time );
}
```

but I've got to do this hundreds of times. I've used [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) but I couldn't find how to do this with it.

Apart from meeting the clients coding standards, the reason I want to do this is that I have to replace certain calls such as the above call to `setDateTime( date, time )` with `setDate( date )` and `setTime( time )` which I can easily enough do with regular expressions but ends up like this:

```
if ( myCondition )
    setDate( date );
    setTime( time );
```

Obviously not right!!!

Comment: I don't know about tools for this.  Re regexp substitution, you can always substitute `{ setDate(date); setTime(time); }` - it doesn't matter if there's an extra level of `{` and `}`.

Comment: Now we've learned that we should always use brackets in the first place :) On a sidenote as well, If you have control over the `setDateTime`, I guess you could modify it to call `setDate` and `setTime` respectively?

Comment: @Michael: Great point and thanks also Steve Jessop for pointing this out. My client is moving from one subsystem to another and ideally, it would be nice to have a completely clean break and use the new API without any 'helpers' to make it look like the old API. These are fine, but could get confusing down the line when no-one knows why the helpers were introduced (incidently, the setDate etc are just examples, not the real thing which is a bit more involved.) That said, it all comes down to how quickly (read: cheaply) this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static inline void setDateTime(date, time) { setDate(date); setTime(time); }`

Regarding the `if`: does the astyle option `--add-brackets` not work for you, combined with `brackets=break`? When I've used astyle, I've found it difficult to get it to do exactly what I want. So if you're going to use it at all, it's easiest to define the coding style guidelines in terms of a set of astyle parameters and then use astyle to enforce them.

I'm not so bothered by inconsistent style that I personally think that's worth it, but then the customer is always <s>grudgingly tolerated</s> right.

Comment: Thanks, looks as if --add-brackets seems to do exactly what I want. That said, I haven't tried it yet. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/setDateTime(date, time)/{ setDate(date); setTime(time); }/
```

Comment: Thanks. Granted that does work, however it has the odd but usually harmless side-effect that *all* setDateTime() calls get bracketed even if they are not conditional. After this has passed again through AStyle, the resultant code looks, well, odd - A code block in the middle of no-where for no apparent reason.

Comment: Isn't simple text replacement like this, what macros are for? To the extent that they're for anything, I mean ;-)