# JavaScript 'if' alternative

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

What does this bit of code represent? I know it's some kind of `if` alternative syntax...

```
pattern.Gotoccurance.score != null ? pattern.Gotoccurance.score : '0'
```

What's the need for this sort of coding? Is this more efficient or just a shortened version with the same efficiency?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is the [conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Operators/Special_Operators) operator, and it is equivalent to something like this:

```
if (pattern.Gotoccurance.score != null) {
  pattern.Gotoccurance.score;
} else {
  '0';
}
```

But I think that an assignment statement is missing in the code you posted, like this:

```
var score = pattern.Gotoccurance.score !=null ? pattern.Gotoccurance.score : '0';
```

The `score` variable will be assigned if `pattern.Gotoccurance.score` is not null:

```
var score;
if (pattern.Gotoccurance.score != null) {
  score = pattern.Gotoccurance.score;
} else {
  score = '0';
}
```

A common pattern to do this kind of 'default value' assignments in JavaScript is to use the logical OR operator (`||`) :

```
var score = pattern.Gotoccurance.score ||  '0';
```

The value of `pattern.Gotoccurance.score` will be assigned to the `score` variable only if that value is not *falsy* (falsy values are `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, zero-length string or `NaN`).

Otherwise, if it's falsy `'0'` will be assigned.

The performance will be equivalent, and you should focus on readability. I try to use the ternary operator on expressions that are very simple, and you can also improve the formatting, splitting it up in two lines to make it more readable:

```
var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult"
                         : "minor";
```

Related question:

- *[To ternary or not to ternary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)*

Comment: Oh, ok gr8, why need for this sort of coding, is this more efficient or just shortened version with same efficiency?

Comment: Does the interpretation time affect performance?

Comment: This is the kind of answer that makes a difference. No more doubt when it comes to JavaScript and the ternary operator. Well done CMS.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), a shorthanded way to do if statements.

If re-written, it would look like this:

```
if (pattern.Gotoccurance.score != null) {
   return pattern.Gotoccurance.score;
} else {
   return '0';
}
```

Comment: "ternary" just means "function with arity of 3."  ... ? .. : ... is the Conditional Operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the ternary operator.

Comment: It is *a* ternary operator.  It happens to be the only one in the language, but there could be other theorhetical ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

As to the need for this sort of coding:

You can sometimes use the ternary operator to reduce complexity:

For example, I have a web page which needed to verify that *at least* two out of three specific text fields had values entered.  The if/else logic looked pretty ugly, but the ternary operator made it a one-liner to determine how many fields were filled in:

```
var numberFilledInFields = ( (firstName.length > 0 ? 1 : 0) +
                     (lastName.length > 0 ? 1 : 0) +
                     (zipCode.length > 0 ? 1 : 0) );

if (numberFilledInFields < 2)
{
    validation = false;
    return;
}
```

This solution appears quite elegant and easy to read than some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ternary operator/conditional operator.

In mathematics, a [ternary operation](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&defl=en&q=define:Ternary+operator&ei=bWD2Su_gFqWK6AOovNgD&sa=X&oi=glossary_definition&ct=title&ved=0CAcQkAE) is an n-ary operation with n = 3. A ternary operation on a set A takes any given three elements of A and combines them to form a single element of A.

It is a short hand form of *if..else*.

E.g., to want to find out if a number is even or not.

#### Using the *if..else* approach

```
function CheckEvenOdd()
{
    var number = 2;
    if(number % 2 == 0)
        alert("even");
    else
        alert("odd");
}
```

#### Using ternary

```
function CheckEvenOdd()
{
    var number = 2;
    alert((number %2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd");
}
```

#### Using switch

One more variant is switch:

```
function CheckEvenOdd()
{
    var number = 2;
    switch(number % 2)
    {
        case 0:
            alert("even");
            break;
        default:
            alert("odd");
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, if you have a simple *if..else* condition to perform like the one described, you can go ahead with ternary.

**But if the conditional checking becomes complex, go either with *if..else* or *switch* as readability will be lost in ternary.**

For example, it is easy to get the minimum or maximum of two numbers using a ternary operator, but it becomes clumsy to find the largest and second largest among three or more numbers and is not even recommended. It is better to use *if..else* instead.