# What is "?:" notation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, coding-style, operators, notation

I found this snippet of code in my travels in researching JSON:

```
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
```

I'm seeing more and more of the `?` and `:` notation.  I don't even know what it is called to look it up!  Can anyone point me to a good resource for this? (btw, I know what `!=` means).

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript if alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688337/javascript-if-alternative)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's called a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).  It's essentially a condensed if-else.

So this:

```
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
```

...is the same as this:

```
var array;
if (typeof objArray != 'object') {
    array = JSON.parse(objArray);
} else {
    array = objArray;
}
```

Comment: Actually it is CALLED a conditional operator, but it IS A ternary operator. A ternary operator is any operation that takes 3 inputs. In many contexts, however, ternary operator has become synonymous with conditional since the conditional is either the most famous or sometimes the only ternary operator present in that language. For example, ++ -- are called unary operators, and + - / are called binary operators, etc.

But that's just semantics, good answer, plus 1. :)

Comment: @Razor – Nice addition; also have a look at the ECMAScript 5 specification of the [Conditional Operator ( ? : )](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.12).

Comment: @Razor - +1 for your comment, and [according to the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator) the conditional operator is the only ternary operator in Javascript.

Answer (score 13):

It's the ternary conditional operator --
basically,

```
if (condition) {
   a = 4;
}
else {
   a = 5;
}
```

becomes

```
a = condition ? 4 : 5;
```

Comment: Like Razor pointer out in the accepted answer: It's actually the [JS conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is the only ternary operator in JS.

Answer (score 11):

That’s called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator):

> ```
> condition ? expr1 : expr2
> ```
>
> If `condition` is `true`, the operator returns the value of `expr1`; otherwise, it returns the value of `expr2`.

Answer (score 2):

Just read it like this:

```
result = (condition) ? (true value) : (false value);
```

place what ever you like in the 3 operators.

As many has compared it to an IF.. THEN structure, so it is.