# Java Script syntax

Tags: javascript

```
    options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
```

can some one explain me what is the purpose of putting ? after options.domain. I know it's simple. but i'm little new to JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript ? : notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322704/javascript-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [**`ternary operator`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) **`?:`** (single line **`if..else`** statement)

> **Syntax:** `var variableName = testCondition ? op1 : op2;`

I guess you missed the assigned variable

```
var dom = options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '';
```

equivalent to

```
if (options.domain) {
   dom = '; domain=' + options.domain
}

else {
  dom = '';
}
```

Comment: Also you have to take a look at this [**Truth, Equality and JavaScript**](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you very much...Praveen Jeganathan

Answer (score 0):

It's known as a ternary operator, essentially these are equivalent:

```
// Item 1
var x = options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '';

// Item 2
var x;
if (options.domain) {
    x = '; domain=' + options.domain;
} else {
    x = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ternary operator is like simple if,else statement like:

```
condition ? option1 : option2 ;
```

is similar to

```
if(condition)
{
option1;
}
else
{
option2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an similar type of `if` statement.

```
return condition ? x : y;
```

Ternary operator logic is the process of using `"(condition) ? (true return value) : (false return value)"` statements to shorten your if/else structures.

Answer (score 0):

That's called `ternary operator`. It returns one of two expressions depending on a condition.

Syntax:

```
test ? expression1 : expression2
```

***test* :**

> Any Boolean expression.

***expression1 :***

> An expression returned if test is true. May be a comma expression.

***expression2 :***

> An expression returned if test is false. More than one expression may be a linked by a comma expression.