# Javascript shorhand syntax

Tags: javascript

What does this mean?

```
var min = minimum ? minimum : 15;
```

Encountered in the following context:

```
 tempApp.filter('minimum', [ function() {
return function(arrTemp, minimum) {
var arrReturn = new Array();
var min = minimum ? minimum : 15;
angular.forEach(arrTemp, function(value, key){
if(value.temp>=min) arrReturn.push(value);
});
return arrReturn;
}
}]);
```

Comment: and [javascript ? : notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3322704/218196)

Comment: and many of those: [`[javascript] "?" ":" meaning`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22%3F%22+%22%3A%22+meaning)

Comment: Or just do `var min = minimum || 15`. But careful with zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shorthand version of

```
if(minimum) {
  min = minimum;
} else {
  min = 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(minimum) {
  min = minimum;
} else {
  min = 15;
}
```

Comment: That's not even correct. If `minimum` is `"foo"`, then `mininum == true` is `false`, but is still considered true-ish in `var min = minimum ? minimum : 15;` (because non-empty strings evaluated to `true`).

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to show the concept of `true-ish` to OP, but you are right.