# Javascript check if a decimal is negative

Tags: javascript, decimal

How would i check if a decimal is negative? Because the if statement automatically turns it into a number...

Example:

```
var x = -0.24324;
```

how would i parse it so it tells me `x` is negative/positive?

Thanks

Edit: Maybe i phrased it badly, the variable changes so something it will be positive like `0.00000001`, sometimes `-0.0003423423`, sometimes `0.0000000234`

If i put it in a if statement everything is automatically turned into 0 right? And i can't use a parseFloat in the if statement?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. Why can't you check `if (x < 0)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571717/javascript-negative-number)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `x` less than zero since it's a number:

```
if (x < 0) {
  // it's negative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `isNaN()` function to check whether it is valid number or not.
2. If it is, then you can check for positive or negative value.

Something like this:

```js
var x = "-123"
var y = -456;
var z = '-123a';

if(!isNaN(x) && x < 0) {
  console.log(x + ' is negative');
}

if(!isNaN(y) && y < 0) {
  console.log(y + ' is negative');
}

if(!isNaN(z) && z < 0) {
  console.log(z + ' is negative');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const num = -8;

// Old Way

num === 0 ? num : (num > 0 ? 1 : -1); // -1

// ✅ ES6 Way

Math.sign(num); // -1
```