# How to ignore a negative number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I understand that `Math.abs` is used to convert negative numbers to absolute in JavaScript, but say I want to filter out negative numbers in an `array` for example, how do I do that? Is there a function for that?

Comment: "Ignore" as in filter them out of the array?

Comment: Can you define "ignore"? If you just want the control flow to skip over it, a simple `if(num < 0)` would suffice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571717/javascript-negative-number - please refer to following

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your issue `[1, 2, -3 , 4, -5].filter(val => val > 0);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eliminate the values, @Antoni 's approach will do.

However, if you want to retain elements but bound the values (also known as clamping) I usually use `Math.max(0, number);` to set a lower numerical bound - if `number` is <0, it returns 0.

You can apply this to an array using [`map`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp):

```
var array = [1, -2, 3];
array = array.map(number => Math.max(0, number));
//Sets array == [1, 0, 3]
```

Similarly for an upper bound you can use `Math.min(upperLimit, number);` and of course you can apply them both for upper and lower bounds:

```
var array = [1, -2, 3];
const lowerLimit = 0;
const upperLimit = 2;
array = array.map(number => Math.max(lowerLimit, Math.min(upperLimit, number)));
//Sets array == [1, 0, 2]
```