# simple javascript question

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript ? : notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322704/javascript-notation)

what does the "?" operator mean?

Comment: So this ternary operator walks into a a bar...

Answer (score 3):

it means an inline if

condition ? true_statement : false_statement

e.g

```
if(condition){
alert("true");
}else{
alert("false");
}
```

is the same as `condition ? alert("true"): alert("false");`

Comment: For reference, the conditional operator's true and false parts should be values, not actions.  I'd recommend `alert(condition ? "true" : "false")` instead -- though in this particular case, `alert(condition.toString())` may work as well.  Either way, if you have to decide between two actions, use `if`/`else`; if you're deciding between two values, use `?:`

Comment: I was just showing that it can work just as a regular if, though you are right, it can be used like return (condition ? "ok" : "nope");

Answer (score 1):

It, along with `:` comprises the `ternary operator` and is a shortcut for returning one of two values (the second and third sub-expressions), based on the result of the condition (the first sub-expression).

Wikipedia gives a good description: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Javascript

**It's used like this:**

`var result = (condition ? value_for_true : value_for_false);`

**Example:**

```
var result = (1 > 0 ? "It is greater" : "It is less");
```

The above example stores `"It is greater"` in the variable `result`.

On its own, `?` does nothing except cause a syntax error when used without `:`.

Comment: thanks, looked on google but it took the "?" to mean question.

Comment: Sure. It's a common feature in many languages by the way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F. Not just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the [**ternary operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

```
// This simple if
if (25 > 23) {
    alert("yes");
} else {
    alert("no");
}

// Is the same as
alert(25 > 23 ? "yes" : "no");
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean the `?:`, or ternary, operator. Since this has been covered multiple times before, I'll refer you to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688337/javascript-if-alternative) for a full explanation.

Comment: It's actually the [JS conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is the only ternary operator in JS.

Comment: Ya know, people are gonna get rather confused if there ever ends up being another ternary operator.  They won't know what to call the existing one anymore.