# java equivalent of ruby's ||= syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I'm brand new to java, coming from a ruby world.  One thing I love about ruby is the very terse syntax such as ||=.

I realize of course that a compiled language is different, but I'm wondering if Java has anything similar.

In particular, what I do all the time in ruby is something like:

```
someVar ||= SomeClass.new
```

I think this is incredibly terse, yet powerful, but thus far the only method I can think of to achieve the same thing is a very verbose:

```
if(someVar == null){
  someVar = new SomeClass()
}
```

Just trying to improve my Java-fu and syntax is certainly one area that I'm no pro.

Comment: Oops answered this for C# which in C# would be `somevar ?? (somevar = new SomeClass())` if Java has the null coalescing operator also it should work equivalently (I assume).

Comment: @Chris - You mean `someVar = someVar ?? new SomeClass()` :)

Comment: @Nick No I mean exactly what I said, atleast in C#. A real world example of it would be `public List<string> Strings { set { _strings = value; } get { return _strings ?? (_strings = new List<string>()) };`. Now if only I could specify an auto property that the get is self generating if it's null. Something perhaps like `public List<string> Strings { set; safe-get; }`

Comment: @Chris - Yes, but the equivalent of his ruby statement is what I posted :) `someVar ||= SomeClass.new` == `someVar = someVar ?? new SomeClass()` in C#, it's the assignment as well as the fetch, just very short in ruby.

Comment: While my knowledge of ruby is very limited, I believe my version is the literal intepretation for C#. I assume in ruby you can do `return someVar ||= SomeClass.new` you can't do `return someVar = someVar ?? new SomeClass()` you can do my versions. If you can't do the `return someVar ||= SomeClass.new` in ruby then it doesn't matter which way it's achieved with in C# whether it's if/else, ternary, or null coalescing assignment or null coalescing self assignment.

Comment: @Chris - You can return that in ruby, also in C# you can return any assignment, including `return someVar = someVar ?? new SomeClass()` , try it :)  but...you're not doing a return in ruby with this *most* of the time, just preparing it to use a few lines down.

Comment: You are right on that I was arguing the wrong point, what I should've been speaking on was that regardless of whether the variable is set you're assigning itself again. That's functionally different than `if set return me else set me return me` especially since you could apply that to a property which could have a complex setter and introduce almost impossible to track bugs. Albeit that code would probably be bad to start with if assigning itself to it could cause side effects but it would still cause potentially duplicate assignments whereas mine doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's not. But to replace

```
if(someVar == null){
  someVar = new SomeClass()
}
```

something similar is scheduled for Java 7 as [Elvis Operator](http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=ddb3zt39_78frdf87dc&hl=en):

```
somevar = somevar ?: new SomeClass();
```

As of now, your best bet is the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
somevar = (somevar != null) ? somevar : new SomeClass();
```

Comment: I don't generally support the combination of Java  and mid-1900's rock-and-roll, but in this case I'll withhold my objection.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best you could do is the ternary operator:

```
someVar = (someVar == null) ? new SomeClass() : someVar;
```

Comment: I had to read this 3 times to figure out how it would evaluate somevar = (somevar == null)... Clever, but I wouldn't want to be the guy that gets stuck maintaining this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think ternaries are usually considered clever, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218 . I guess you get used to them.

Comment: YIKES! I read that completely wrong... for some reason, my brain read that as "if(somevar=(somevar==null))..."   so it looked like it was evaluating the outcome of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in Java. Part of the reason for this is that `null` is not considered `false`.

So, even if there was a logical OR-assignment keyword, you have to remember that:

```
Object x = null;
if (!x) { // this doesnt work, null is not a boolean
```

Comment: This is one of the things I miss most about C compared to other high level languages if(obj) should evaluate to obj != null. I find it really stupid that it's been removed from us.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you could add a method to SomeClass similar to

```
public static someClass enforce(someClass x)  {
 someClass r = x.clone();
 if(r == null){
  r = new SomeClass();
 }

 return r;
}
```

And call it like

```
someVar = SomeClass.enforce(someVar);
```