# What, if any, is the performance effect of lots of ternary conditionals?

Tags: php, performance, ternary-operator

If I use a lot of ternary conditional operators in my PHP, will it adversely affect the performance of my script?

e.g.:

```
$var = (cond)?"success":"error";

if(cond) success else error
```

I prefer to use ternary conditionals, because it makes the code look cleaner and smaller.

Comment: Clean and small code is loses to maintainable and readable code every time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To ternary or not to ternary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)

Answer (score 4):

> If I use a lot of ternary conditional operators in my PHP, will it
>   adversely affect the performance of my script?

No.

---

> ```
> $var = (cond)?"success":"error";
> ```

This is a ternary conditional (or "inline if")...

> ```
> if(cond) success else error
> ```

... but this is just a normal `if`-`else` statement, lacking newlines and braces. It's functionally identical to:

```
if (cond) {
   success
}
else {
   error
}
```

---

> I prefer to use ternary conditionals, because it makes the code look
>   cleaner and smaller.

Not necessarily. So be careful with what appears to be a gross generalisation you are making in your style decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you define inline for us? Using:

```
$var = (cond)?"success":"error";
```

or

```
if(cond) { 
   $var = "success";
}else{
   $var = "error";
}
```

Shouldn't give you any noticable performance difference. However, if you plan on having inline as in HTML mixed with your PHP:

```
$var = "success"
echo "<p>$var</p>";
```

I would suggest checking out template systems such as smarty.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it depends but generally you wont notice the difference in performance. Normally If the test condition is a small amount of data the performance can be almost the same. But with larger sets of data you can see slower performance with the ternary operator.

I would suggest using it if that's what you like in your code and only concern yourself with it if your code is really starting to crawl.

link to a post doing so performance tests : http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not