# What's the meaning of these Java operators?

Tags: java, operators

This question may sound dumb but I honestly can't find an answer anywhere...what does the operators "^=", "|=" and "?" mean in Java? Thanks..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html - typing "java operators" into google provides that as the first link. Where were you looking?

Comment: You should take a look at some tutorials for java. Here is an oracle page on operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `x ^= y;` means the same as `x = x ^ y;`.

The `^` operator is bitwise exclusive OR, the `|` operator is bitwise OR (see [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)).

Just like `x += y;` means `x = x + y;`, etc.

For `?`, see [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

Comment: and ? is used as a IF function   a = condition ? true : false;

Comment: @AlejoBrz - it's called `ternary`

Answer (score 1):

- `x^=y` is short for `x = x^y`
- `x|=y` is short for `x = x | y`
- `?` is the conditional operator. It's a shortcut for an if / else statement. It's use is highly controversal.

Comment: It's called a `ternary` operator and why would you ever say it's "controversial" ?

Comment: @BrianRoach I perhaps wouldn't call it controversial but some people dislike it as it can make code less readable.

Comment: @Jim - And I'd ... politely disagree with you :-D I've never worked with or met anyone who finds them difficult to read or expressed a dislike in any language, never mind just java. I use them when they're a good fit.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ternary and conditional are synonyms. Your and Jims comment are a good example for the controversal debate. I personally use it, when it fits (what has to be defined).

Comment: @BrianRoach [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary) is the first hit searching SO for "ternary" it includes discussion about the name and the use.

Answer (score 1):

They're all covered by the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

The question mark is used in the ternary operator, which is a shorthand for if-then-else. For example,

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println ( i == 0 ? "No" : "Yes" );
```

If `i` is 0 then "No" will be printed, otherwise "Yes" will be printed.

The other two are used in [bitwise assignments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
|= assignment operator -> bitwise inclusive OR
^= assignment operator -> bitwise exclusive OR
? logical operator as in booleanValue == true ? something() : somethingElse()
```

Comment: `? :` is the `ternary` operator.

Answer (score 0):

- `^` is the XOR operator
- `|` is the bitwise OR operator
- `?` is the ternary operator.

The first two have the `=` operator after them because that's a shortcut writing. For example `x |= y` is the same as `x = x | y`.

More details about them can be found on thosands of websites on the Internet.