# Syntax in Java math operations (bitwise or equals)

Tags: java

Google doesn't seem to help with the following: in Java, what does the following mean?

```
long_num1 |= long_num2
```

Comment: The list of java operators does, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of these Java operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685260/whats-the-meaning-of-these-java-operators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Means `long_num1 = long_num1 | long_num2`.

The `|` is bitwise OR.

Answer (score 5):

It's a **bitwise OR** logical operation.

```
1 | 0 = 1
1001 | 0101 = 1101
11110000 | 00001111 = 11111111
```

It's commonly used when one has to deal with [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). The `long_num` values store multiple Boolean flags as individual bits of the whole integer.

Note however that Java has a built-in feature for dealing with bit fields: the [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.