# What does the `|=` symbol means in the Java code "anyMatches |= match"

Tags: java

I have encountered `"anyMatches |= match"` online where anyMatches and match are both boolean values. I was just wondering what does the symbol `|=` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the short form for `anyMatches = anyMatches | match`

Comment: thank you so much for helping out! do you mind telling me what does | mean in this context? thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's **bitwise or**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704230/syntax-in-java-math-operations-bitwise-or-equals and please next time search for your answer on google before posting a question.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! will take it on board