# PHP Shorthand If/Else

Tags: php, shorthand

I want two things to happen when this is true. It's working fine, but i'm not sure is this good programming.

```
$a =1;  
($a == 1) ? (($b= 'val1') && ($c= 'val2')) : null;
echo $b . '<br/>';
echo $c;
```

I could simply write with if else but this way, it's smart. please help me...

Comment: *"this way, it's smart"* - no, it's not...

Comment: No, actually it's not smart; it's just showing off. Good for learning, but not good for real world code. You should use an `if`.

Comment: smart? i think it's more smarter is to write code so everyone easy understands. I would try avoid ternary operators, it confuses matters.

Comment: I don't think this way is smart, smart code is clean code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To ternary or not to ternary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)

Answer (score 1):

Simple ...

```
<?php
$age = 20;
$status = ($age >= 18) ? "adult" : "kid";
echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you quoting `$status`?!

Comment: xD because i had some text and then i removed it and forgot to remove the quotes, my bad ...

Answer (score 1):

It's bad. You should use `if` is this situation, it fits better.

Notice that mixing PHP and HTML in one file is bad. You must use template engine for this ([Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), for example). Otherwise it can't be called good programming anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thats **BAD** style. NEVER should it be used in real code.

BTW. if you are keen on exploring, even this should work for you:

```
<?php
$a=1;
$a==1 && ($b='val1') && ($c='val2');
echo $b;
echo $c;
?>
```

That comes from [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: $a =1;
  if($a == 1){
   $b= 'val1';
  $c= 'val2';
  }

this is what i want to do with that short hand code
yes i could use this method without messing up
but i just test it

Comment: Your code is the recommended approach. Do not try something obfuscated.

Answer (score -1):

If the first condition matches, the second and the third will be evalued.

```
$a == 1 AND $b = 'val1' AND $c = 'val2';
```

Comment: This is SQL code? This does not seem to fit the question at all.

Comment: It's PHP. The OP wants to achieve "compact code" and I use it often. At least try it first before down vote.

Comment: i didn't down vote, i only commented.