# Should the ? Operator Be Used More Often?

Tags: c, operator-keyword, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To ternary or not to ternary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)

Today, while reading through my C book I stumbled upon a little gem: the `?` operator. It is a ternary operator that acts like an if else statement based on weather or not a statement is true or false.

Apparently using the `?` operator is supposed to be more efficient.

The following code uses an if / else statement (assuming somefunc returns NULL on failure):

```
foo = somefunc();
if(foo) printf("\nFunction Suceeded!");
else printf("\nFunction Failed!");
```

This is code is the same as the first but uses the `?` operator:

```
somefunc() ? printf("\nFunction Suceeded!") : printf("\nFunction Failed!");
```

I can see how this will not be useful most of the time, however I know I've seen countless instances where this could have been easily used in place of an if / else statement.

Is it good practice to use this method?

Comment: Its more about readability, the use of the ternary operator can less to difficult to understand code, especially if you use a nested one.

Comment: `printf(somefunc() ? "\nFunction Suceeded!" : "\nFunction Failed!");`

Comment: @Vlad that's really cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency aside, you should use whichever is more readable.

Efficiency included, if the `?` were *really* more efficient, the compiler would definitely automatically rewrite any `if` statements to `?` expressions. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary operator sparingly. It's definitely useful and can be an appropriate abbreviation, but it also can lead to less readable code. Your example demonstrates this.