# self-referencing ternary

Tags: python, idioms, ternary

I've been doing this for a while:

```
x = x if x else y
```

In all sorts of contexts where x might be `None`, `False`, `0`, `''`, `[]`, or `{}`.

I know the purists would rather I:

```
if not x:
    x = y
```

but forget that, that's not my question. **My question** is:

Is there anything 'wrong' with `x = x if x else y` besides the fact it's a ternary? Specifically, is it ok to have a ternary self-assign like that.

**NOTE**

My qustion is *not* is `x = x if C else y` ok. I know it is.

Many thanks

Comment: The bad thing is that `x` is calculated twice. Use `x = x or C`

Comment: @shhdup Awesome, but why did you just leave a comment? I would have accepted that answer. I didn't think of x = x or C. I guess it's time I start studying other people's code.

Comment: @shhdup the reason ternary expressions were introduced was to stop people from using the confusing "and", "or" equivalent versions.
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Comment: @Scruffy Reputation is the last thing I need on SO :) Everything for the sake of light forces!

Comment: If `x` is an expensive function call, then you can split it on two lines.
`f = x(); x = f if f else C`.

Comment: @ashwini-chaudhary Wow, I'm surprised. And as I now do without my favorite chains of `or`? :(

Comment: but wait... doesn't shhdup actually have the right answer here? I'm not asking about ternary in general, I am asking about the specific self-assigned x = x if x else y.  I think x = x or y is much more concise in this special case?

Comment: My (Edward's) answer doesn't actually answer your question, sorry. But it's related and I think it's interesting, so I'll leave it there. The answer to your specific question is: yes, it's ok to have ternary self-assign like that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using ternary for `x = x if c else y`, however, in the case of `x = x if x else y` the logic really does just reduce to

```
x = x or y
```

This is because in Python `x or y` evaluates to ['if x is false, then y, else x'](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

So `x if x else y` == `y if not x else x` == `x or y`

Obviously, `x or y` is the clearest and should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, nothing wrong with it.
It's very pythonic in fact. I recall reading that that's the preferred (by Guido himself) ternary-equivalent. I'll see if I can dig up the reference.
Personally, I find the other way more readable, but you didn't ask for my personal opinon. ;)

UPDATE:
Here's the citation.
Core Python Programming, 2nd ed.; Wesley J. Hun; Prentice Hall 2007

> If you are coming from the C/C++ or Java world, it is difficult to
>   ignore or get over the fact that Python has not had a conditional or
>   ternary operator (C ? X : Y) for the longest time. [...] Guido has
>   resisted adding such a feature to Python because of his belief in
>   keeping code simple and not giving programmers easy ways to obfuscate
>   their code.   However, after more than a decade, he has given in,
>   mostly because of the error-prone ways in which people have tried to
>   simulate it using and and or - many times incorrectly. According to
>   the FAQ, the one way of getting it right is (C and [X] or [Y])[0]. The
>   only problem was that the community could not agree on the syntax.
>   (You really have to take a look at PEP 308 to see all the different
>   proposals.) This is one of the areas of Python in which people have
>   expressed strong feelings.   The final decision came down to Guido
>   choosing the most favored (and his most favorite) of all the choices,
>   then applying it to various modules in the standard library. According
>   to the PEP, "this review approximates a sampling of real-world use
>   cases, across a variety of applications, written by a number of
>   programmers with diverse backgrounds." And this is the syntax that was
>   finally chosen for integration into Python 2.5: X if C else Y.

Comment: Thanks Edward. But what about (X ? X : Y) as opposed to (C ? X : Y) or is it the same thing?

Comment: That would be `X if X else Y`, but that simplifies to `X or Y`.

Comment: Yes, as MarkReed says, (X ? X : Y) is a special case of (C ? X : Y) - but a special case that can be simplified and made clearer.

Answer (score 1):

From a language design point of view, nothing is wrong.  As another poster mentioned, it's even the preferred way.  I would even ask you why do you imply that being a ternary is wrong?

From a readability/maintainability point of view, things are a bit more databable.  On one hand, if you are going to have a lot of casual, non-Python readers/maintainers, this construct (as opposed to `if not x: x= C`) could be much less readable.  On the other hand, your program will most probably contain many other (and much deeper) Pythonisms.  You have a right to expect a minimum of knowledge from your "readers".

From a performance point of view, `x` being a variable both forms are optimizable (if not effectively optimized) by the different implementations into the same code.  Meaning no difference in these terms.

UPDATE:

I didn't know Guido's opinions on the subject cited by @Edward.  I'm glad he agrees with me.  Or I with him.  But he was absolutely right about introducing the ternary operator, as it is much clearer than alternatives like `x= (x,C)[not x]`  or  `x= x or C`, which had been used (and promoted) by many early Python programmers with a C background (and perhaps also as a "cool", differentiating thing).  BTW, both are generally correct (depending of the exact semantics intended).

Comment: I don't think the cited passage is applicable to x = x if x else y. Most people are looking at this question as if it asks if x = x if c else y is ok. That is not the question.

Comment: @Sruffy  Sorry, what "cited passage" ?

Comment: Edward was the one who brought up Guido, and he cites a passage about it in his answer.

Comment: @Scruffy Absolutely. Just that I referred to it, but didn't cite it. Will edit my answer to be clearer. I mainly meant the fact that readability (as opposed to its extreme opposite of obfuscation) is the critical issue. And, no: if you check the examples I used, you will note that I'm referring **exactly** to the case you are asking about.  Not to the general `C ? X : Y` (to use C's syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to do this, because here's my real opinion:

Don't micro-optimize.  Use what you are comfortable with; use what makes your code most readable.  The ternary statement is perfectly fine if that is what you feel is most readable.

That said,

```
ben@nixbox:~$ python3 -m timeit 'x = 1; x=x if x else 2'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0345 usec per loop
ben@nixbox:~$ python3 -m timeit '''
> x=1
> if not x:
>     x=2
> '''
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0239 usec per loop
```

There is some small overhead in assigning x back onto itself.

```
dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12 
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) #this is the extra instruction
              9 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 15) 
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
        >>   15 STORE_FAST               0 (x) 
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Back to my main point: don't worry about it.  Use what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think `x = x if x else y` has bigger problems though: it is not concise and therefore obfuscates the true logic: `x = x or y`

Comment: @Scruffy but `x or y` expands to a ternary _itself_: "if x is false, then y, else x".  "True logic" is a misnomer when they are doing the same thing, it just comes down to what makes sense to you.

Comment: @Scruffy  In many cases readability depends on problem domain language. Or at least that's the main criterion I use when I have a choice. For example, in a scientific/mathematical application a calculation could perfectly well be given by `(A,B)[δ(C,D)]` (I missed a good formula editor here). It's more natural (and legible) to express that formula as `(A,B)[C==D]` than `A if C==D else B`.

Comment: @Scruffy  I mean that if  `x= x or y`  sounds more natural to you and your coworkers and/or final users, then go ahead, that's the best choice.

Comment: @roippi IMO the optimization phase of the compiler is not very smart if there is a difference. If there is no case in which both alternatives produce different results (even if slightly), then there is no reason why the compiler would produce different object code.  And I can't think of any !!! :-(  Agree with your "no" to micro-optimization.  Legibility and robustness should always come first.