# Cannot check an Element of ArrayList<Object> if it has null value in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Game>` and my object game consists of `Date`,`Opponent`,`Score` and other fields counting 10 elements.

Sometimes `Score` maybe `null`.
How can I check this and change it to some default value?

I tried the following:

```
for(Game a : arrList)
{
  if(a.getScore() == null)
  {

  } 
}
```

I need to do the `if(..)` 10 times or there is another faster way?

Comment: Can't you just initialize the score to your default value when you declare it in your `Game` class?

Comment: no way to improve your  code unless you can initialize the score attribute with default value in the game class

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "do the if(...) 10 times"? Maybe you could let `Game.getScore` return an `Optional` and use `a.getScore().orElse(defaultValue)` instead of `a.getScore()` everywhere. Or even introduce a `Game.getScore(defaultValue)` getter.

Comment: Why does iterating over 10 elements bother you? There is no reason to overengineer it.

Comment: You could do the check/ return a default value from the getter...

Comment: @mhenryk, I think you misread the question. There are 10 fields in Game, not 10 elements in the list.

Comment: Score is an object?

Comment: @user1506104, no, `Score` is a *class*.

Comment: I am getting null in a Game element when I query my db and return an Arraylist<Game> so I should set it while inserting my record correct?

Comment: What is the type of score ? I don't think so it is class

Comment: @Vickyexpert, not sure I understand your question, but OP mentions a `Score` class in his first sentence.

Comment: If it is class then show your score class with all properties

Answer (score 2):

In your class Game, you can put a default value for score :

```
class Game{
     private Score score;
     public Score getScore(){     
         return this.score == null? this.score : new Score();      
     }
}
```

For your information : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (byte)0.
>
> For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (short)0.
>
> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>
> For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>
> For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>
> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
>   '\u0000'.
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.
>
> **For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.**

In your class Game, you can put a default value for score :

**EDIT:**

```
class Game{
     private Score score;
     public Score getScore(){     
         return this.score;      
     }
     public void setScore(Score score){     
         this.score = score;      
     }
     public Score getScoreOrDefault(Score default){
         if(Objects.isNull(this.score)){
              setScore(default);
              return default;
         }
     }
}
```

And after you can call getScoreOrDefault in passing a new Score as a parameter:

Comment: As an extension to this solution and because you might want to keep your pojo behaviour as clear as possible, add some getter methods like _getScoreOrDefault(Score default):Score_.

Comment: you're right, i edited my code following your comment

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it in right way but still if you want more performance then you can use `ternary operators` inside `loop` as follows

```
(a.getScore()==null)? a.setScore("value"):do nothing;
```

Comment: i don't think that has any performance improvement over a simple 'if', both are compiled to the same java byte code.

Comment: @marmor I read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613124/cannot-check-an-element-of-arraylistobject-if-it-has-null-value-in-android/39613354?noredirect=1#39613705) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary). I will be keen to learn if you have more references

Answer (score 1):

You could update the `getScore()` method in `Game` to return `Optional<Score>`:

```
public Optional<Score> getScore() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(score);
}
```

Then when you call it you can use [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) with a `Consumer`:

> If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value,
>   otherwise do nothing.

```
game.getScore().ifPresent(score -> 
    System.out.println("This is only executed if the value is present!"));
```

**Example**

```
public class Game {

    private Score score;
    private String name;

    public Game(String name) { this.name = name;}

    public Game(String name, Integer scoreVal) {
        this.name = name;
        score = new Score(scoreVal);
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public Optional<Score> getScore() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(score);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
        games.add(new Game("Game 1"));
        games.add(new Game("Game 2", 10));

        for(Game game: games) {
            game.getScore().ifPresent(score -> 
                System.out.println("Score value in " + game.getName() + " is " + score.getValue()));
        } 
    }
}

class Score {
    private Integer value = 0;

    public Score(Integer val) { value = val; }

    public Integer getValue() { return value; }
}
```

*Output*

```
Score value in Game 2 is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Java 8 Syntax
via this way you can check in list which fastest
arrList
.stream()
.filter(p-> p.getscore()==null)
```